# CSS Hover colour and <li>

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu bar I've written in CSS. I want to make each `<li>` have a different background colour only when the mouse hovers over it. This works.

However I also need to change the colour of the text in the `<a>` within the `<li>`'s when the hover happens.

This is what I have so far:

```
.horizontalMenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.horizontalMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000
}
```

However this is not changing the text colour within the `<a>`.

I've tried:

```
.horizontalAppMenu li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
```

However this has the effect of only changing the text colour when the actual link is hovered over not the whole menu section.

How do fix this?

Comment: Give your html script. if possible make a jsfiddle.

Comment: It could be anything... a typo, precedence, etc. Without knowing what the rest of your code looks like it is difficult for us to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.horizontalAppMenu li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Older versions of IE such as IE6 won't support pseudo selectors on anything other than A tags, but all modern browsers support it.

Comment: I doubt this is an IE6 problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.horizontalAppMenu li:hover a {
   color: #000;
}
```